# How to pretty print JSON to a file in Clojure?

Tags: json, clojure, pretty-print

I would like to store JSON content in files but using the pretty version.

Just to be clear, this is the normal JSON:

```
{"b":2, "a":1}
```

This is the pretty version of it:

```
{
    "b": 2,
    "a": 1
}
```

Is there a way in Clojure to achieve this?

Comment: The `pprint` function in [*clojure.data.json*](http://clojure.github.io/data.json/) looks like what you want. I suppose you can do the write on another thread if diverting `*out*` is a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the cheshire library found [here](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire) 
and use the generate-string function with the pretty flag set to true

Example

```
;; generate some JSON with pretty formatting
(generate-string {:foo "bar" :baz {:eggplant [1 2 3]}} {:pretty true})
;; {
;;   "foo" : "bar",
;;   "baz" : {
;;     "eggplant" : [ 1, 2, 3 ]
;;   }
;; }
```

Comment: Should also consider my solution below if you don't want or need an external library.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the built-in `with-out-str` function to capture anything written to the output buffer and store it as a string.

```
(with-out-str (clojure.data.json/pprint your-map-or-whatever))
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid capturing to an internal string buffer and writing (or spit'ting) straight to a file?